# Extract value in column which is a list with json inside

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Agent   Info
A       [{"id": 0, "value": 235, "hours": 40}]
B       [{"id": 1, "value": 771, "hours": 64}]
C       [{"id": 2, "value": 879, "hours": 70}, {"id": 2, "value": 879, "hours": 85}]
```

I want to extract values from column `Info` and turn them into separate columns, so the output looks like this:

```
Agent   Info_id  Info_value   Info_hours
A       0        235          40
B       1        771          64
C       2        879          70
C       2        879          85
```

How could I do that? I have no idea, I'm not good in JSON.

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` ?

Comment: @RonakShah no, its an example of real data (which is huge and contains some private information) to show a structure

Comment: `dput(head(df))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` in `tidyr`.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Info = map(Info, fromJSON)) %>%
  unnest(Info)

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Agent    id value hours
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A         0   235    40
# 2 B         1   771    64
# 3 C         2   879    70
# 4 C         2   879    85
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(Agent = c("A", "B", "C"), Info = c("[{\"id\": 0, \"value\": 235, \"hours\": 40}]", 
"[{\"id\": 1, \"value\": 771, \"hours\": 64}]", "[{\"id\": 2, \"value\": 879, \"hours\": 70}, {\"id\": 2, \"value\": 879, \"hours\": 85}]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: cool, and how to make it "Info_id" not just "id" and so on?

Comment: @french_fries just add a pipe line: `%>% rename(Info_id = id)`